# How to load translated entity values in Twig for SEO purpose?

Tags: theming, 8, i18n-l10n

How can I get access for the english values of my entity in the french version of my twig template. This is for a tracking task.

Let say I want to print the node title en english on the french version.

I was hoping I could do something like this : `{{ node.languages.en.label }}` but this doesn't work.

I'd rather avoid using preprocess if possible (I know how to do it with preprocess).

Comment: Stop thinking in D7 templates and start using hook_preprocess.

Comment: Well I do already, but actually I'm not thinking in D7 templates but in Twig templates meaning using the less hook_preprocess possible for the frontend developer to have more freedom on their twig templating. I have 30 templates to edit with various values to get so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the translated node with [getTranslation()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3AgetTranslation/8.4.x):

```
{% if node.hastranslation('en') %}
  <p>{{ node.translation('en').title.value }}</p>
{% else %}
  <p>No translation<p/>
{% endif %}
```

If you are not sure that the translation exists, check first with [hasTranslation()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3AhasTranslation/8.4.x), because a missing translation throws an exception.

Comment: Well thank you very much, this was exactly what I needed. BTW, {{ node.translation('en').label }} works fine too in my case :-)

Comment: Yes, I've used the title field for the example, because the question was about entity values. But you can use a method like label() on the translated node, too.