# How to get entity Translation's title in Twig

Tags: views, 8, theming

i am trying to get row title -node title- in my custom module 
with  `template_preprocess_modulename_view($variables)` and `views-modulename-view.html.twig` with using

```
row.content['#row']._entity.title.value
```

but it always return node title of translation source.

how can i get correct node translation title in twig?

--

**update:**

i am going to clarify my problem:

i have a view which returns nodes without any condition-
example of returned output is like:

```
- 'title of node 1 in english'
- 'title of node 1 in french'
```

i want to  manipulate title in twig but 
`row.content['#row']._entity.title.value` returns always node 1 in translation source language. -in this case english-

is it possible to get exact title of row -considering translation and language of returned row- in twig?

**update 2**

in `template_preprocess_modulename_view($variables)` i tried:

```
  $rows = $variables['rows'];

  foreach($rows as $index=>$value){
    if (isset($value['#row'])){
      $row=$value['#row'];
      var_dump($row->_entity->get('langcode')->value);
    }
  }
```

but `$row->_entity->get('langcode')->value` returns language of translation source of row, not language of row itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load translated entity values in Twig for SEO purpose?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248619/how-to-load-translated-entity-values-in-twig-for-seo-purpose)

Comment: @leymannx thanks but it uses node.hastranslation('en') but i don't know what is language of that row - i didn't filter a special language in that view-

Comment: You can add `$variables['current_language'] = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();`in preprocess and use `current_language` in place of `'en'`

Comment: @Clive  is it possible to get language of row in template_preprocess_modulename_view($variables) with something like $rows = $variables['rows'];  then looping and get language from $row['content']['#row']?

Comment: @Clive about \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId(); i searched a little and it seems it returns language of page. how we can return language of row with it?

Comment: If it's a view can't you just add it as a field and make it available that way?

Comment: @Clive i think it 's not good idea to make the module dependent on a specific views' field because end user can remove that field.

Comment: Every view has a setting "Language" (very bottom of the middle column) where you can choose "Content language selected for page", have you set that?

Comment: @leymannx yes. it is content language of view row and it is exactly what i want. i updated my question. maybe it is more clear now

Comment: It actually makes it more unclear to me now. You have a view of node titles, one for each row. And now you want to display in each row all available translations per node?

Comment: @leymannx sorry about poor knowledge of english. no, just row title but it returns wrong title in twig -it always returns node title of original language-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you filter rows having all the same language, but you don't have to. So rows can have different languages.

The code in the question seems to get the entity from the wrong place. See this topic for examples of different kind of rows: [How to access raw data in twig template using views table format](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278890/how-to-access-raw-data-in-twig-template-using-views-table-format)

A normal views row is a ResultRow object having the property `_entity`, which then should return the translated entity:

```
$entity = $row->_entity;
```

See [ResultRow::$_entity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ResultRow.php/property/ResultRow%3A%3A_entity/8.7.x)

But it doesn't. Tested it with the pre-installed view Content and I had to get the entity translation of the row language stored in `node_field_data_langcode` before I could get the translated title:

```
foreach (views_get_view_result('content') as $row) {
  $entity = $row->_entity;
  $langcode = $row->node_field_data_langcode;
  $entity = $entity->getTranslation($langcode);
  $translated_title = $entity->label();
}
```

Comment: thanks. i tried and i updated my question again.

Comment: @user780 – `$row->_entity->get('langcode')->value` probably always returns the source language. But what does `$entity = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($row->_entity);` get you?

Comment: @leymannx             $t=\Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($row->_entity);
      var_dump($t->get('langcode')->value); return en for all rows

Comment: @user780 – Get the title value.

Comment: @leymannx english title for of all rows which is not correct like langcode

Comment: @user780 – Damn!

Comment: @leymannx your suggestion and 4k4's in update 2 has not same results but both are incorrect.

Comment: @user780 – You probably need to follow Clive's suggestion then.

Comment: getTranslationFromContext() gets the translation from the request context, not from the views row. Try to get the row from somewhere else. Can't help you with that because I don't know this hook: template_preprocess_modulename_view

Comment: @leymannx Clive's suggestion in loop in update2 always returns en too.

Comment: @user780, had some time now to test it and I found a solution

Comment: @4k4 Thank you so much for your time. it works great now. just two things: 1- you were right. i used views-view--[view-display-type].html.twig and it has nothing to do with module_name 2- you use $row->_entity directly after loop but i have to add $row=$value['#row']->_entity; after loop in preprocess function or use row.content['#row']._entity in twig to get correct result. why? what is difference? there is any documentation to read about that?

Comment: I wouldn't dig into row.content, because this is a render array and everything you find there can change without notice. A render array is not an API, it is only required to have valid render elements in no particular order. Use the View object to get the rows: `$rows = $variables['view']->result;`

Comment: @4k4 in preprocess function it works great but what about twig file?. there is no $variables to get rows. how to pass $rows from $rows = $variables['view']->result; to that twig?

Comment: In Twig `view.result`, see the question I've linked in the answer.