# How can I get the render language for a views in views field plugin

Tags: 8, views

I need to write a views field plugin, where I need to display a message depending on if the render language exists for an entity. (i.e. entity languages: en, hu, fr display language: de -> message needs to show up, i.e. entity language: en, hu, fr display language: en -> no message)
But for this, I can't get the language from the views. I can get the settings with `$this->view->display_handler->getOption('rendering_language')` but this can contain also dynamic values like `***LANGUAGE_entity_translation***` or `***LANGUAGE_entity_default***`. I looking for a solution that can give me a specific language code that was made by the rendering language setting.

Comment: This is a rather complex question because there are so many ways to configure languages in Views. Your best chance is the row property `node_field_data_langcode`. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283627/how-to-get-entity-translations-title-in-twig

Comment: That's not correct for me, because I need to align to the views settings, not a constant setting form the node itself. I can't believe that views don't have a function or property for this somewhere deep in the forest.