# how to get translated content in twig [views.view.unformatted]?

Tags: views, 8, theming, i18n-l10n

I am trying to get translated node title in my custom views-view-unformatted twig file.
Here is the way I am retrieving my node title in twig file

```
<div class="col-md-6 title">
    {% for row in rows %}
   <strong>{{ row.content['#row']._entity.title[0].value }}</strong>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

By the above code I can only retrieve the English node title but translations aren't there even though my query selecting based on **Interface text language selected for page**

Comment: You have to translate the node to the language you find in each row: `node_field_data_langcode`. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248619/how-to-load-translated-entity-values-in-twig-for-seo-purpose and https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283627/how-to-get-entity-translations-title-in-twig

Comment: thanks, this was helpful https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248619/how-to-load-translated-entity-values-in-twig-for-seo-purpose